# Initialize Sales Force Connection in WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2-esb

I am following steps from https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Configuring+Salesforce+Connector+Operations

I am confused where can I **putt/init** the following code
because there is no location or file name described.

```
<salesforce.init>
    <username>MyUsername</username>
    <password>MyPassword</password>
    <loginUrl>https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/27.0</loginUrl>
    <blocking>false</blocking>
</salesforce.init>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just add this to your proxy configuration. That's all

```
<proxy name="salesforce_proxy"
      transports="https http"
      startOnLoad="true"
      trace="enable">
  <description/>
  <target>
     <inSequence>
        <log level="custom">
           <property name="salesforce" value="trying to login"/>
        </log>
        <salesforce.init>
           <username>myUser</username>
           <password>myPass</password>
           <loginUrl>https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/29.0</loginUrl>
        </salesforce.init>
```

Comment: where is proxy configuration located?

Comment: A proxy is a "service" in wso2. Just follow the instructions.   https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/Working+with+Proxy+Services

Answer (score 1):

Before carrying out any other Salesforce operations, we have to add init component. You can refer the sample proxy[1] which is used to do a createCompany operation in ActiveCollab.

We have another way to add the init component in "Local Entry"[2] and using "configKey"[3] to call that local entry component in each operation.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Working+with+Companies+in+ActiveCollab#WorkingwithCompaniesinActiveCollab-sampleconfiguration

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Adding+a+Local+Entry

[3] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Working+with+sObjects+in+Salesforce#WorkingwithsObjectsinSalesforce-describeGlobal